# How to get FLUTTER text field `inputTextFormaters` using mobile number enter first enter zero value remove?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

How to get FLUTTER text field  `inputTextFormaters` using mobile number enter first enter zero value remove?

Comment: Please explain it in detail

Answer (score 0):

You question is not clear enough. But if you are trying to remove first zero from phone number while country code already contain zero, then this example will remove fist zero from number !. I don't know , is this the answer you looking for or not. If it works or not let me know !

```
 static String removeLeadingZero(String str) {
    var regex = RegExp(r"^0+(?!$)");
    str =  str.replaceAll(regex, "");
    return str;
  }
```